# Relating mismatched column in an xsd?

Tags: visual-studio-2008, reporting-services, join, dataset

I am using VS 2008 and trying to create a dataset for ms sql reporting services.  I have two tables that I want to relate.  One has a column with type of int, the other shortint.  VS give me an error of

> Parent and Child columns don't have type-matching columns.

Is there any way to over ride this?  In old sql reporting services I could just use a query and get around this problem.  I cannot change the type of either of the column.

TIA

**EDIT**
Jonathan, thanks for the response, but I am not able to touch the structure of the tables.  There may be lots of reasons for this.  Some tables in my systems are feeds from legacy systems.  I do not have control over some of the systems.  This has got to be a huge problem for any large company.

Comment: You said in your question that you're creating an XSD dataset. Try altering the columns in the *XSD TableAdapters* to create the relation.

Answer (score 0):

What are the DataTypes of the `int` and `shortint` DataColumns in the DataSet?

If the `int` column is `System.Int32` then can you change the `shortint` column to the same?

This should allow a Relation to be made using the two columns.

Answer (score 0):

Are you certain the mismatch will never be a problem? What about rows in the `int` table with values > `2^15 (32,768)`? These could not be related to the `shortint`.